# Not sending put request angular

Tags: angular, ionic3

i am trying to send a put request but it did not return any response at all. When i pass the same request with postman i get a 200 response.

```
updateDriverLocation( latitude, longitude, id)
  {
      let driver = {
          activity: 'online',
          value: true,
          long: longitude.toString(),
          lat: latitude.toString()
      }

      let header: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
      header = header.append('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
      header = header.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.access_token);

      this.http.put(this.base_url + 'driver/' + id,  driver, {
        headers: header
    }); 

      console.log(this.base_url + 'driver/' + id);

  }
```

Why is it not sending any request?

Comment: is there any error that is being thrown  in your browser/server console?

Comment: none... so tiring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Http.put returns an observable which only executes if you subscribe to it. Subscribe to the observable returned by the http.put. That should solve your issue.

```
this.http.put(this.base_url + 'driver/' + id,  driver, {
    headers: header
}).subscribe(result => {})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are a life saver

Comment: I need your help for a slightly different issue. Can i ask here?

Comment: You should open a new Question for that, as will get confusing for other people if we continue here